Raspberry Pi connected to wifi but cannot access the internet
My raspberry pi suddenly stopped accessing to the internet, even though it's still connected to the wifi. It's a Raspberry Pi 5. The OS is Bookworm 64-bit. It's just a simple wifi SSID and password connection. I've rebooted, checked the wifi credentials and reset the router.
I've tried:

Pinging both 8.8.8.8 and my default router, there's no results for either.
Pinging google.com, the results came back as "Temporary failure in
name resolution."
Checked ip a && ip r. It looks good AFAIK.
Checked the /etc/resolv.conf file. The DNS servers listed are correct.

I've also tried:
Disabling and masking NetworkManager and NetworkManager-wait-online.
Then made /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf look like this:
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    
country=MyCountryCode

network={
        ssid="myssid"
        psk="mypassword"
}

Then I did sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0 -B -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log
After that I looked at the log cat /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log and it looked like this:
Succesfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan

If there were no errors the plan was to then try sudo dhclient -v wlan0, and then try pinging again. But there were errors so I couldn't get that far.
I have another micro sd card with Bookworm OS that connects to the internet correctly. I redid all the steps on it to compare the output of wpa_supplicant.log on that one. Here is what it shows:
Succesfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
GROUP=netdev'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.

wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0

There's something wrong with wlan0 or nl80211 on the card without internet, but I can't decipher what is happening.
These 2 cards are 2 separate projects, so I need them both to work and access the internet. I've put a lot of time into the card that is not accessing the internet, so I want to avoid reinstalling the OS if possible.
Thank you in advance. I really appreciate anybody's help.

I doubt "pi suddenly stopped accessing to the internet" You seem to have tried all the poor advice and obsolete settings in one! Too many to bother commenting individually. Just do a fresh install and use Network Manager, don't fiddle with it and it should work - this is the future (used by most Linux for 10 years)

I haven't done anything but just check the basics, one of them being your suggestion of  ip a && ip r. The only other thing I tried was a suggestion from @goldilocks , trying to get me connected back to the internet. I really can't do a fresh install, I've put too much work into it. I had done nothing different or fiddled with it when it just stopped working.

ahh, I thought I'd seen this question before

"Disabling and masking NetworkManager" is NOT nothing "Checked ip a && ip r. It looks good AFAIK" is OK if you understand networking - in which case you wouldn't need to ask.

I was following a list of things to do from goldilocks... disabling NetworkMananger, then the next step was updating /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf, then sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0 -B -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log and then looking at the log, if that was successful I was hopefully going to get back on the internet, but it didn't work.

@Jaromanda yes I accidently leaked my IP address I had to delete the question

@Milliways I then of course re-enabled NetworkManager after following the instruction list from goldilocks and it didn't work

Link to this "advice" goldilocks, while undoubtedly extremely knowledgable does not use standard network settings as he has admitted many times. You would be better following Raspberry Pi Ltd. recommendations. Just undo all the changes you did (or restore from your backup) is you don't want to start again. Shotgun changes to networking just make things worse. Frankly I have absolutely no idea what your current settings are.

Try running What networking system is my Pi using?

What kinds of settings? It's the most simple set up. I changed nothing.

@Milliways I tried. I'm getting a lot of command not found with that script. print_head: command not found and checkactive: command not found

This is impossible. Those are functions in the script.

I thought so. But I checked my other working card and OS, and it's doing the same thing. Command not found.

Is the pi working well otherwise? Can you run scripts?

Yes everything else works just fine
